# Next.js 13 appDir: Fetch user on the server using express session cookie

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have an API using express-session and I wanted to get the user in a server component / create a middleware for Next.js to check if the user is authenticated.

Fetching the user in a server component didn't work because the server doesn't know my session cookie / id and the fetch result is always `null`:

```
// app/dashboard/page.tsx
import React, { Suspense } from "react";

async function getUser() {
    const user = await fetch("http://localhost:3100/trpc/user.me", {credentials: "include"}).then((res)=> res.json())
    console.log(user) // null
    return user
}

const Comp = async ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) => {
    const user = await getUser()
    return (
        <>
            <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading user...</div>}>
                <div>{user.displayName}</div>
            </Suspense>
        </>
    );
}

export default Comp;
```

So then I thought I could create a middleware and pass on my session cookie, but this also didn't work:

```
// middleware.tsx
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'
import type { NextRequest } from 'next/server'

export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {

    const sCookie = "xid";
    
    const session = request.cookies.get(sCookie)?.value
    console.log(session) // s:w43gRjd whatever

    async function getUser() {
        const user = await fetch("http://localhost:3100/trpc/user.me", {credentials: "include"}).then((res)=> res.json())
        console.log(user) // null
    }
    getUser()

    const response = NextResponse.next()

    // Add session cookie to response
    if (request.cookies.has(sCookie)) {
        response.cookies.set(sCookie, session!)
    }
    return response
}

export const config = {
    matcher: [
        "/((?!api|_next/static|favicon.ico).*)", // don't execute middleware when hitting static assets
    ],
}
```

Has anyone got any idea on how to solve this?
Thanks! :)

Edit: This is how I solved it. You have to manually include the cookie in the request.

```
const xid = cookies().get("xid")
    
if (!xid) return null
    
const user = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/user.me`, {
   credentials: "include",
   headers: { Cookie: `${xid.name}=${xid.value}`}
}).then(res => res.json()).then(res => res.result.data)
```

Comment: Did you find a fix?

Comment: I've edited my post to include a solution